# Derivative of exponential of sum of non-commuting matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, operator-theory

Given two square real $m \times m$ matrices $A$ and $B$, which will generally not commute, and given the function
$$f(x)=e^{A+Bx}$$
Where $x$ is a real variable, is there an expression for the derivative $f'(x)$? Due to the fact that $A$ and $B$ may not commute, I can't write $e^{A+Bx}=e^A e^{Bx}$, therefore it seems to me that the usual way to prove the expression of the derivative of the exponential for real functions does not extend to this case.

Comment: I think you can get something from the Zassenhaus formula but it looks pretty annoying: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#Zassenhaus_formula

Answer (score 1):

You can use the series definition of the exponential.
Since
$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}(A+xB)^n = \sum_{k=1}^n (A+xB)^{k-1} \,B\, (A+xB)^{n-k}
$$
you get
$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}e^{A+xB} = \sum_{1\leq k\leq n\leq \infty} \frac{(A+xB)^{k-1} \,B\, (A+xB)^{n-k}}{n!}.
$$

Comment: You forgot the sum from $n=0$ to $n=\infty$ on the right-hand side. You also switched the order of $x$ and $B$. Otherwise, it looks fine!

Comment: No, I wanted to mean a double sum for all the $1\leq k\leq n <\infty$. The term $n=0$ vanishes. I prefer to put scalar in front of vectors, so $xB$ instead of $Bx$ ($Bx$ looks like the product of the matrix $B$ with a vector $x$ for me). They commute anyway ...

Comment: Ah, that is perfectly reasonable. I did not realise $x$ was just a scalar in $\mathbb{R}$, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

A closed form formula for the [derivative of the exponential map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_of_the_exponential_map#Statement) is given by $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} e^{X(x)} = e^X\phi(-\mathrm{ad}_X)X'$, where $\phi(x) = \frac{e^t-1}{t} = \sum_{n\ge0} \frac{t^n}{(n+1)!}$ and $\mathrm{ad}_XY = [X,Y]$. In the present case, one has $X = A+Bx$, hence $[X,X'] = [A+Bx,B] = [A,B]$ and finally
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} e^{A+Bx} = e^{A+Bx}\phi(-\mathrm{ad}_A)B = e^{A+Bx} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\mathrm{ad}_A^nB}{(n+1)!}.
$$
I'm afraid we cannot do much more without information about the commutator of $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d}{dx}e^{A+Bx}=\int_0^1e^{(A+Bx)(1-u)}Be^{(A+Bx)u}du.$$

Comment: What is the proof of this formula?

Comment: LL.3.14 49: Just use you own formula below and the value of $\int_0^1 u^m(1-u)^kdu$ when $m$ and $k$ are integers.